# How to use Python fetch data from HANA DB without data format values?

Tags: python, database, hana

I tried to use `pyhdb` module to fetch data from HANA DB, and below is the code:

```
class HANA:
def __init__(self):
    self.conn = pyhdb.connect(
        host="#", port=30015, user="#", password="#", autocommit=False
    )

def getMARA(self):
    cursor = self.conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM "odw.sup.cmn.sl4.ssv::SUP_MBEW" limit 100')
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    return result

C = HANA()
rst = C.getMARA()
for i in rst:
    print(i)
```

but the results include the data format, e.g.

```
('400', '02.098.0380', '2007', '', '', Decimal('0'), '', datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 8, 12, 24, 35), Decimal('0'), 'V', Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('1'), '9103', Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), 'V', Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('1'), '9103', Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), 'V', Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('1'), '9103', Decimal('0'), '2010', '03', '', Decimal('0'), '00000000', Decimal('0'), '00000000', Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), '00000000', '00000000', '00000000', '000000', '000000', '000000', '', '', '', '', '', '', Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), '00', 'BG', '000115393025', '000115393026', '', '', '', '00', '00', '00', '', '', '000', '000', '000', '0000', '0000', '0000', '', Decimal('0'), '', '', Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), 'X', '', '', '00000000', '', Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', Decimal('0'), '', '', '', '', '', '', '2132')
```

How could I get the data with decimal & datetime symbol, just the data value?

Comment: `Decimal('al('0'), Decimal('0'))` looks like invalid value, string is not quoted properly. Please, copy and paste your result. Also what do you mean "format"?

Comment: @astentx I have put the full result in the question. And the format means the type of the data, like String, Integer, Boolean

Answer (score 0):

`fetchall` returns you a list of tuples, so printing each row will print it formatted as tuple definition. To convert it to strings use [unpacking argument list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments) for print.

```python
>>> def print_cursor(cur):
        res = cur.fetchall()
        colnames = [i[0] for i in cur.description]
        print(*colnames, sep=',')
        for r in res:
            print(*r, sep = ',')

>>> cursor.execute("select top 3 o.*, cast(1 as decimal(10, 3)) as dec_example, current_timestamp as tstmp_example from objects as o where schema_name = 'SYS'")
>>> print_cursor(cursor)
OBJECT_CATEGORY,SCHEMA_NAME,OBJECT_NAME,OBJECT_TYPE,OBJECT_OID,DEC_EXAMPLE,TSTMP_EXAMPLE
None,SYS,ABSTRACT_SQL_PLANS_,TABLE,189055749,1.000,2020-11-18 02:32:08.755000
None,SYS,ADAPTERS_,TABLE,1395238,1.000,2020-11-18 02:32:08.755000
None,SYS,ADAPTER_CAPABILITIES_,TABLE,1395249,1.000,2020-11-18 02:32:08.755000
```

But it is just for printing. To work with data you'll need it in correct datatypes, so no additional conversion is required.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can get the return value without data type now, but how could I upload the fetch data to other DB? It seems that I can only print, but cannot store the data in list or convert the data to string. Here is the code: `for r in result: print(*r, sep="','")` and here is the result: `0000743188XX','REP622653/XX','20201121','ROR1010071/1RXX','1234','610`

Comment: and I try to use list to store, here is the code : `rst = [] rst.append(*r)`, but it pops up error: TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (6 given)

Comment: @EricGong What do you want to append to result set? Please, describe your issue in more details. Also you should read about unpacking one more time, because the error message is quite clearly describes the error.